# Angularjs: Why page refresh destroy the values of $rootScope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, local-storage

In my local route http://localhost:9000/#/deviceDetail/ I have a controller that manage that view. Before going to that view I set some variables to the `$rootScope` (*for example `$rootScope.dashboards`*).

Once on that view I have acces to dashboards property, but when I refresh the page with `F5` key for example the property dashboards is lost.

I tried to save the `$rootScope` on the localStorage variable but I got circular reference problems with the `JSON.stringify` method.

Any tip to manage that?

Comment: you can try with this [angular module](http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html)

Comment: I think your problem is that you're not using a proper router and are failing to load necessary data on route change, instead of an action like "click".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AngularJS is a JavaScript framework, everything is stored in memory heap and the heap is starts when you open a page and it's destroyed after you close it. In this context, browser refresh is like closing and re-opening the page.

To keep the value after refresh, you should store it in a cookie, for this you use for example [`$cookies`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) / [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) as recommended by M K.

Comment: Cookies is actually a bad idea. You should use localStorage instead.

Comment: I recommended it because `$cookies` are in angular by default, but you have to do access localStorage in "vanilla way" or add additional module.

Comment: OP did say they tried `localStorage` and ran into problems. You answered the `why` but not the `how`

Comment: Because the storage is not the problem. I'm 90% sure he is doing the loading of data in a click event handler and not in the router - which is the actual problem.

Comment: @charlietfl OP also didn't provide the code that is accessing the storage, therefore I have no way of knowing what's wrong to explain how to do it correctly.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak as I said in the coment I used localStorage, using JSON.stringify I got circular reference error, I will give a try to $cookies.getObject(key);

Comment: @MarkoGrešak the circular error appear here: localStorage.setItem('root', JSON.stringify($rootScope));

Comment: I'm sure this error isn't related with JSON.stringify, but with something else you're doing. Maybe stringifying just the things you need and not whole `$rootScope` would be a good thing to start with. And also more efficient.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak I need the entire object , $cookies of angular 1.3.15 only stores strings values, and also with JSON.stringify I can not convert the $rootScope object to json string becuse of the circular reference, any other approach?

Comment: There is no way you should ever need whole rootScope, if you do, you're doing it wrong. Store only the values from rootScope that you're adding and load them in rootScope when page is opened. You could probably do this with localStorage too.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to store auth token using cookies following the article at [Getting started with AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC - The long awaited Part Three](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/843044/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-The). But the cookies is destroyed whenever I hit F5 or refresh the Chrome browser.

That article says ngCookies helps to deal with page refresh to maintain token for page refresh. And I had thought it did and I did not know ngCookies killed me. It was destroyed if page is refresh! after hours to research online I see this article helps me.

According to M K, I used localStorage (or sessionStorage) helped me to get rid of the headache of cookies. **Using cookies to store authentication token or something else is a bad idea**. I ran into that problem and I got lost (did not know the bug coming from "using cookies") as the above article mentioned/confirmed. So, it was a bug in that article.

Thank you million times, M K.

Comment: Had exactly this problem, there was a bug in the article!

I solved it by importing ngStorage in app.module and used `$localStorage` and the following code in my session service:

`this.getToken = function () {
 if (!$localStorage.myApp) {
  if (!this.token) {
   return undefined;
  }
  this.setToken(this.token);
 }
 return $localStorage.myApp;
}

this.setToken = function (token) {
 this.token = token;
 $localStorage.myApp = token;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage and $stateChangerStart check if you using ui.route 
something like this

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

            // Grab the user from local storage and parse it to an object
            var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));            

            if(user) {

                $rootScope.currentUser = user;

            }
        });
```