# angularjs rootscope user database info from firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to fetch user info from user's database and access it from anywhere using rootscope.
 I get the user's email and uid as the user signs in.
 However,to get the user's info from database, I need to call my database and read the info one by one and store it as a variable in rootscope to access it from everywhere.

So, my question is below :

- How can I use rootscope in this example?
- Is there any better way to do this?
- in the below example, the console log is showing the first name, but I don't know how to rootscope it?

Thanks for help.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$cookies', "$location",
function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $cookies, $location) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {

            $rootScope.user.uid = user.uid;
            $rootScope.user.email = user.email;

            return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

                var firstname = snapshot.val().firstname;
                console.log("first name", firstname);

            });
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
        }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) **Always use its wrapper methods** vs native firebase methods.

Do not use

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid).once('value')
```

Use

```
$firebaseAuth().$onAuthStateChanged
var userData = $firebaseObject(firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid));
```

Checkout the following link for full list of available methods in [angularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire).
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md

I recomend modifying your code like this.

```
$firebaseAuth().$onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      $rootScope.user = $firebaseObject(firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid));
      $rootScope.user.uid = user.uid;
      $rootScope.user.email = user.email;
      console.log("Here you should have complete user object");
      // still if you want to do something when user is loaded
      /* $rootScope.user.$loaded(function(loadedUser) {
            var firstname = loadedUser.firstname;
            console.log("first name", firstname);
        });*/
    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
    }
});
```

Of course you need to include `$firebaseObject` and `$firebaseAuth` using dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to fulfil your needs

**Approach 1:**

you can do this `$rootScope.authData=user;` then access it from anywhere by injecting `$rootScope`. but problem in this is that when you will refresh page `$rootScope` will be empty Check this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849825/angularjs-why-page-refresh-destroy-the-values-of-rootscope)

**Approach 2:**

I will prefer this approach,you can use use `$getAuth()` function of `angularfire`, `$getAuth` is syncronous function which will gives you current user data.

```
var myUser=$scope.AuthObj.$getAuth();
```

for [more detail check this](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#getauth)

Comment: could you please write a complete answer and how to adapt it to my code? i am confused a bit.

Comment: which version of firebase you are using

Comment: got it, you can write `var myUser=$firebaseAuth().$getAuth();` in any controller to get signed in User info.