# How to re-populate rootScope after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, refresh, rootscope

Reloading my AngularJS Web Application clears my $rootScope.
How can I store my $rootScope the easiest way, so that it survives a page refresh?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can save data in localStorage of browser.

Comment: Can I save the complete $rootScope?

Comment: Please go through this link for better understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849825/angularjs-why-page-refresh-destroy-the-values-of-rootscope

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's understand what the $rootScope is/does.

[The official angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) tells us that *scopes*, using watchers, provide a clear separation between the model and the view. 
The $rootScopeProvider is a scope that is unique to the whole angular application: think about it as a shared object that can be accessed from every controller, service, factory, etc.

You use the $rootScope by adding a new property to it. That property will be immediately available in all the other components that inject the $rootScopeProvider due to its watchers.

Now, let's take your use case of $rootScope and try to understand it: 
as long as the application is running and you programatically add a property to $rootScope it will be populated and you can use the value of that property within your app:

```
// ... 
$rootScope.property = true;
// ...
```

If you, however, try to dynamically populate the **$rootScope** with Objects and information that is not intended to be stored as a $rootScope property, those will be flushed away the next time you refresh you application because you have simply not re-created the same behavior programatically as in a previous state.

People do not recommend using $rootScope at all, but if you actually need to use it, think a little bit more on the use case. If you, for example, want to do an http POST at login, receive a response and store that response in a global variable, there might be better services (providers ) that suit your needs - such as $cookies , localStorage or simply persisting the data in a database.

Comment: I want to store the user data after login in my rootScope JsonObject. I tried to save it in sessionStorage, but after refreshing the page the data is also gone..